# Touching triangles at their vertices

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry, optimization

What is the minimum number of non overlapping congruent triangles arranged in the plane,
such that each vertex of the triangles coincide with exactly three triangles?

Comment: Can someone give me an example of this?

Comment: @risky In case you haven't seen it yet, check out Jaap's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of triangles in my best solution is

> 20

but I don't know if this is optimal.

> If you take kites formed from four 30-30-120 triangles, you can place a number of them in a ring, like this:
>  [image]
>  This picture shows six such kites because that was easiest for me to draw, but you can remove one and make a loop with 5 kites, for a total of 20 triangles. @humn kindly made a picture of that:
>  [image]
>  If you use four kites then they start touching each other, so you'll get too many triangles at a vertex. @humn made a picture of that too:
>  [image]

**Addendum:**

I previously had an incorrect solution, as I used similar triangles instead of congruent ones (i.e. I used some triangles of a different size but the same shape). As requested by @humn, I'll keep that incorrect solution with 12 triangles available below:

> The triangles are 20-80-80 isosceles triangles so that three can go together to form the corner of an equilateral triangle. There are then 3 smaller copies needed in the middle to fill things up and make sure there are three triangles at every vertex.
>  [image]

Comment: These triangles are not congruent. They are only similar (same angles, different side lengths)

Comment: @happystar I have changed my solution, so now it should be valid.

Comment: I think the four kite (16 triangles) solution is valid if the condition is taken to mean each vertex is a vertex of exactly three triangles.

Answer (score 3):

A liberal interpretation of “coincides”
in the puzzle statement ...

> “each vertex of the triangles
> *coincides* with exactly three triangles”

... allows for a vertex to touch a *side*, and not always another vertex,
of another triangle as in these failed attempts ...

[image]

... that led to this pair of ...

> ... **16**-triangle liberally-interpreted solutions.
>  
>  [image]

Comment: Very nice solution, and in my opinion a completely valid one that improves on mine.

Answer (score -3):

suppose plan area is A and no of triangles are n,

A = n * 1/2 * h * b

so if we want n,

n = 2*A /(h*b), that is the minimum no of triangle